# Regular Expression . confuses me

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I have `Pattern.compile("^[.]+");`. It just matches the `.` character.

I changed it to `Pattern.compile("^.+");`, then it matches any character, either in JavaScript.

However, in JavaScript, the `^[\w.]+` matches special character, such as `abc**`. I'm puzzled.

Comment: the `^[\w.]+` can't match special character in Java.

Comment: `^[\w.]+` will match one or more of `\w` = `A-Za-z0-9_` and `.` inside character class will match `.` literal in any sequence. Use `Pattern.compile("^.+");` to match any character one or more time

Comment: You need to escape the `\​`.

Comment: @Tushar but `^[\w.]+`  matches  `abc**` in javascript , not in Java..

Comment: What JavaScript code are you using to make it match `abc**`? That's not possible. It's probably finding a match only in the first 3 letters, and then stopping. Meanwhile, your Java code is probably looking for if the **entire** string matches the pattern.

Comment: @4castle `alert(/^[\w.]+/.test('abc**'));`  shows true in js, `Pattern.matches("^[\\w.]+", "abc**")` shows false in java

Comment: @water.wang [No. It doesn't.](https://regex101.com/r/hG0fJ6/1). I guess you need `$` anchor.

Comment: `.matches()` doesn't accepts second parameter. [Correct use](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) is `str.matches(regex)`.

Comment: @noob it's Pattern's static method.

Comment: @Tushar your tester is comprehensive, the $ added has correct result.  `alert(/^[\w.]+/.test('abc**'));` is actually true in google browser. thank you.

Comment: What do you think `/^[\w.]+/.test('abc**')` does? Why do you think so? Hint: try with `alert(/^[\w.]+/.test('**'));` and compare results.

Comment: @Pshemo I think  it match one or more word characters include `.` literal, `abc**`  should't meet.   I don't  know  why `/^[\w.]+/.test('abc**')` works differently in js and java.

Comment: @water.wang The difference is whether you're *searching for* something to match the regex *within* a string, or matching *the entire* string to the regex. Java and JavaScript can both do both, but in different ways. What you're seeing is not a difference in regex implementations per se, but in how regexen *are used*.

Comment: It seems that your confusion is with the class metachar and not dot.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why `/^[\w.]+/.test('abc**')` works differently in js and java.

`^[\w.]+` doesn't match `abc**`, but a *part* of the string [**does** match](https://regex101.com/r/aO6kN7/1). Depending on how you use the regex, it will either search for a match in the ***whole*** string or a match in ***part*** of the string.

### In Java

To try to match the ***whole*** string, use [`.matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches())

```
Pattern.compile("^[\\w.]+").matcher("abc**").matches(); //false
Pattern.compile("^[\\w.]+").matcher("abc").matches();   //true
```

*Note*: The shorthand for this is is [`Pattern.matches(regex, input);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

To try to match a ***part*** of the string, use [`.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())

```
Pattern.compile("^[\\w.]+").matcher("abc**").find();    //true
Pattern.compile("^[\\w.]+").matcher("abc").find();      //true
Pattern.compile("^[\\w.]+").matcher("**").find();       //false
```

### In JavaScript

To try to match the ***whole*** string, add a `$` to the end of the regex, and then use [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```
/^[\w.]+$/.test("abc**"); //false
/^[\w.]+$/.test("abc");   //true
```

To try to match a ***part*** of the string, just use [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```
/^[\w.]+/.test("abc**");  //true
/^[\w.]+/.test("abc");    //true
/^[\w.]+/.test("**");     //false
```